# In which controller should I place elements that persist throughout the application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Everything after `@posts` should persist throughout the application (Like the left sidebar you find on Facebook).

```
  def index
    @title = "Posts"
    default_order = "content_changed_at DESC"
    params[:order_by] ||= default_order 
    @posts = current_user.subscribed_posts.paginate(:page => params[:page],
                                                    :per_page => 5,
                                                    :order => params[:order_by])
    @subscribed_tags = current_user.subscribed_tags
    @recent_posts = current_user.posts.limit(5).order("created_at DESC")
    @tags= Tag.limit(20).order("ID asc")
    @user = current_user
  end
```

**views/layout/_sidebar.html.erb:**

```
    <div class="user-profile">
      <% avatar = image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => "authenticated-avatar") %>
      <%= link_to avatar, "/users/#{current_user.id}" %>
      <%= link_to "#{current_user.username}", "/users/#{current_user.id}", :class => "authenticated-username" %>
    </div>

    <%= form_for(@user, :remote => true) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :subscribed_tag_names %><br />  
        <%= f.autocomplete_field :subscribed_tag_names, autocomplete_tag_name_posts_path, :"data-delimiter" => ' ', :class => "autocomplete_field" %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit :class => "user_subscribed_tag_names_submit" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="user-subscribed_tags">
      <% @subscribed_tags.each do |subscribed_tag| %>
        <%= link_to "#{subscribed_tag.name}(#{subscribed_tag.posts.count})", unsubscribe_tags_path(:unsubscribed_tag_name => subscribed_tag.name) %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="user-recent-posts">
      <h4>Recent Posts</h4>
      <ul>
        <% @recent_posts.each do |recent_post| %>
          <li><%= link_to recent_post.title, recent_post %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="top-tags">
      <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
        <span class="tag-name"><%= tag.name %></span>
        <span class="tag-count"><%= tag.posts.count %></span>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Where should I place the code in the controller if I want them to persist throughout the application? (I would like to see some example code if possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it persists throughout the application, i.e. for every actions of all controllers, you might place it in a `before_filter` in the application controller.

Add a `before_filter` to the application controller as :

```
before_filter :find_recent_posts_and_tags
```

And define it (as private) :

```
private
def find_recent_posts_and_tags
  # define your instance variables
end
```

More about filters [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) and [here](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Should I place that before or after that `protect_from_forgery` thing (by the way, should I remove that or it is useful)?

Comment: I guess it does not matter if you place a `before_filter` before or after `protect_from_forgery. But, I always seem to see `protect_from_forgery` right at the top(after defining ApplicationController class).
No, do not remove that. It is absolutely necessary to prevent against CSRF attacks. When that feature was developed, it turned out to be so essential that it was enabled by default on all Rails application. Afaik, `protect_from_forgery` adds a `before_filter` that compares the `id` stored in the form as `authenticity_token` against an `id` stored in the session variable.

Comment: So, all generated forms have a hidden id field. If this `id` field fails to match stored `id`, the form submission is not accepted. This prevents malicious forms on other sites from submitting to your Rails application. For instance, if you had another app running elsewhere, say localhost:3001, and you sent a post from there(without the authenticity token) to your current app, then it won't work. You should read more on that to understand it in detail.